# Is there a way to record and playback a set of touches?

Tags: automation, touchscreen

What I'm looking for is some sort of macro-recorder (though that term seems to be hijacked now my macro-photography apps).

I'd like to record a set of presses (specifically, beating a level in a game), and then have those repeated for me so I can accumulate in-game currency without wasting my time or a ton of money.

I imagine there would be other practical uses as well, but I'm not finding anything to do this in Google Play.

MacroDroid and Tasker both looked promising, but you can only assign predefined actions to predefined events - not a set of touches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I record touches?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13992/how-can-i-record-touches)

Comment: @AlEverett This seems different as this question also wants a way to play touches back without user interaction.

Comment: I saw that question, 'seeing touches' as answered there is not at all what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's why it says "possible duplicate".

Comment: https://github.com/Cartucho/android-touch-record-replay

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've developed such an app called RepetiTouch. It's currently in beta stage and aimed at developers, but a limited free version is available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.free). However, it needs a rooted device running Android 2.3 or later.

As far as I know, currently no other app with this functionality exists, but there are some tools/scripts providing such features using a computer and an USB connection, e.g., [here](http://code.lardcave.net/entries/2009/08/01/160953/).

Anyway, I discourage any use of any such apps or tools for farming.

Comment: Neato, I just so happen to be a developer (mostly C# and Javascript, but I tinker), with a rooted S-Off HTC Rezound running CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.2).  Thanks!

Comment: When I open the app I just get "No usable input event file was found." with an -Exit- button.

Comment: Probably your device/touchscreen driver doesn't expose the interface needed by my app, i.e., this particular input event file. However, you can contact me via email so we can find out for sure.

Comment: I wonder if you have a latest version of this application which will be compatible in android marshmallow.

Answer (score 2):

The only app I know of that works fine is ["**Android Bot Maker**"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frapeti.androidbotmaker) (XDA link [**here**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2241770))

sadly, it can't record the touches, but you can set it manually yourself, by finding out the coordinates by enabling "show pointer location" on the developers category of the OS settings.

Answer (score 2):

[HiroMacro Auto-Touch Macro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro) works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Culebra GUI: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI. 
It is a python-based tool that lets you record interactions and re-run them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on an Android Emulator. By using [Memu](http://www.memuplay.com/), you have a button to record and play a script.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to record and playback the events like touching, accelerator, gyro, and etc..
https://github.com/tzutalin/adb-event-record

Answer (score 0):

I had made a java application which does [Android Record N Play](https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer for [123Autoit - NonRoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autoit.nonroot). The latest version has included the function of macro recording and playback action. the app is free to use.

Here is the video demo of the macro recording and playback on YouTube:
[123Autoit nonroot Record and Playback function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8xRc0PZB6Y).

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain this is possible, since I had an app about 6+ yrs ago that did exactly this. I used it to send myself (at another email address) notes of things I wanted a reminder for. After tapping an icon, it would record opening gmail, selecting 'compose', filling in the 'to' spot, then moving the cursor to the content area and selecting the microphone. All set up in an icon.
All I had to do was tap the icon, then start speaking and I got text in the email. then I hit send. I got a new phone and never could find it again! Maybe because of security considerations it wouldn't work today!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).